# Extract a part of values from a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df which has one of the column called "Results". That columns has values like -

```
Results
Movie passed 1 of 3 tests
Movie passed 2 of 3 tests
Movie passed 3 of 3 tests
<empty string>
Movie passed 1 of 3 tests
```

I want to create a new column which extract the number of tests movie passed. In above case, the new column called new_results should have values like:

```
new_results
1
2
3
0
1
```

Please note that it puts '0' in case of null values. How do I achieve this task using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `extract()` method and capture the digits after the word `passed`, if nothing matches, it returns `nan` by default but you use `fillna()` method to replace `nan` with `0`:

```
df.Results.str.extract('passed ([0-9]+)').fillna(0)

#0    1
#1    2
#2    3
#3    0
#4    1
#Name: Results, dtype: object
```